# Does running a batch file from java program destroy piping?

Tags: java, file, batch-file, command, piping

I'm trying to run a batch file from within my Java program, but I'm getting some strange behavior.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start temp.bat");
```

This usually runs okay, but I've found that piping commands in the batch file won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, so when I was running this, any piping commands within my batch file would not work (i.e couldn't have a batch file write output to a text file).  I figured it has because the JRE was grabbing this output for access by InputStream.

Comment: OKAY!  Finally.  Turns out that it has something to do with my IDE (Netbeans).  Piping in my batch files doesn't work when I test my app in my IDE.  But if I run it outside the IDE (build it and run the JAR file), piping works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use CommonsExec which will make your life a lot easier. You could use some code like this (untested):

```
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("ping");
cmdLine.addArgument( host );

ByteArrayOutputStream stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PumpStreamHandler     psh    = new PumpStreamHandler( stdout );

DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor(); 
executor.setStreamHandler( psh );

try {
  executor.execute( cmdLine );
} catch ( Exception e ) {
}

System.out.println( stdout.toString() );
```

Comment: It's a wrapper library for executing external applications in a portable way through Java.

Answer (score 0):

Did you handle the streams from the process? If you do not read them - your process will hang.

What is your exact problem?

**EDIT:** Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973146/how-to-run-command-line-within-java-using-thread-async/5973293#5973293) will help you

Comment: I actually haven't been reading the streams, and I can execute batch files (that don't have piping) fine without any hanging.  Why would this be?

Comment: It can act differently on different operating systems, different hardware etc. Scripts with little output can run fine since they don't overflow the system. The problem only occurs when you fill the streams until they are at full capacity at which time the process hangs.

As for piping - that is very odd, are you sure the scripts using piping don't have more output to them?

Comment: I feel like the root of the problem is that the Runtime.exec() is creating a cmd.exe process. But the cmd.exe process is in turn creating a process to run the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Process object you getOutputStream() and getInputStream() to redirect the I/O from the process.

Comment: I think the problem with this is that the Process p is instantiated for cmd.exe, which doesn't have any I/O because it's immediately calling upon the batch file. I think the batch file ends up being a new process, so p.getOutputStream() and p.getInputStream() aren't going to get the I/O from the batch file's execution.